# Verify webelements on Machine 2 by executing scripts on Machine 1 without starting execution on Machine 2. Is it possible in Selenium or Serenity?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

Assume that I have test scripts on Machine 1 where I have a step where i need to open browser and verify webelements. This webelements verification i have to do on both Machine1 and Machine2. But i have to execute script only from Machine1 and verification has to be performed on both Machine 1 and Machine 2.

Is it possible in Selenium or Serenity?

Let me know if you dont get my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Possible but probably not worth the effort - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Am trying to verify the same data on 2 machines by launching same URL on both machines. But i will execute my automation script only on Machine 1. That particular method where we are verifying the data should execute on both machines.